# UK Customs or TSA removed my TSA lock but didn't leave a note or return the lock, what can I do?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, tsa

I flew to the US on a business trip last month, and locked my soft suitcase with a TSA lock. I did the same on the flight back, but when I got my bag off the carousel at Heathrow there was no lock, no note, and a carrier bag containing a bottle of Hershey's sauce was at the top of the bag instead of in the middle where I packed it. Nothing else was moved, and due to the lack of a note I don't actually know who opened my bag or why.

I know it's not a big deal, but the lock was borrowed and I now owe somebody a lock. My colleague's suitcase was also opened but the lock was inside along with a note from the TSA saying that they searched the bag.

What can I do?

Comment: You can do nothing. I mean you can do anything including tear out your hair however the result will be exactly nothing. Forget it.

Comment: Refund the somebody the lock and take it as a lesson learned? No need to lock suitcases as locks can be opened or broken on every airport.